# Bash replace content between two delimiters

Tags: bash, sed, replace, scripting, character

I have this string:

`test=test1&test2=test3&test3`

My question is: how can I replace all words between = and & with replaced on Bash?

So I can get an output like this:

`test=replaced&test2=replaced&test3`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Write a regex to match from `=` character any characters that follow except a `&` character. 2. Use `sed`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to show their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk thanks for your answer, I am new to the sed command. How can I do what you explained by using it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash "extended glob" for pure bash solution, using the substitue (${var//} operator.

```
X='test=replaced&test2=replaced&test3'
shopt -s extglob
echo ${X//=*([!&])&/=replaced&}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`. Search for a string starting with a `=` and continuing with non-ampersands, replace it with `=replaced`.

```
echo 'test=test1&test2=test3&test3' | sed 's/=[^&]*/=replaced/g'
```

The `/g` means globally, without it, only the first occurrence would have been replaced.